# How to minus stock from several MySQL fields until the Required Stock php loop

Tags: php, mysql

User Enter Stock 300
and Selected Product ID is 252
How to Implement Loop to get Stock(300)From Inventory Table

| Product ID | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 252 | 200 |
| 252 | 10 |
| 252 | 20 |
| 252 | 35 |
| 252 | 200 |

When User Enter the Stock I want to Show Record Like This

| Product ID | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 252 | 200 |
| 252 | 10 |
| 252 | 20 |
| 252 | 35 |
| 252 | 35 |

(This Amount According to Demand in Up Table Last Value is 200)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: your table has no order sp what is last?

Comment: @nbk first i want to search product after stock adjustment i will insert in sale invoice

Comment: Thanks Problem is Solved